# Let $q=p^n$, $p$ prime, ¿Which $q$ satisfies $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}=\mathbb{F}_q(\sqrt{a})$?.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $q=p^n$, $p$ prime, ¿Which $q$ satisfies $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}=\mathbb{F}_q(\sqrt{a})$?. I don't know why is necessary a condition for $q$.

Comment: See the answer to [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/204245/15941) for ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $p\ne 2$, any polynomial $x^2+ax+b$ can be written in the form...